# How to draw the following configuration space (manifold)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, manifolds, geometric-topology, configuration-space

I am studying configuration spaces for robots. For example, the configuration of a two-linked robot can be described as $\mathbf{q}=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and the configuration space is a torus ($\mathbf{Q} = \mathrm{S}^1 \times \mathrm{S}^1$). If I have a omnidirectional 2D robot, my configuration is $\mathbf{q} = (x,y)$ with $\mathrm{Q} = \mathrm{R}^2$, i.e., a plane. In a one-wheeled robot, my configuration is $\mathbf{q} = (x,y,\theta)$, i.e., I need the position and the orientation to describe the state of the robot. Thus, the configuration space is $\mathrm{Q} = \mathrm{R}^2 \times \mathrm{S}^1$. Is it possible to draw this manifold? How can I geometrically interpret this space? Thank you!

Comment: A piece of answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3246986)

Comment: It depends on what do you wan to do with this space; for most purposes, the product description is the best one. If you want to visualize topology of this space, it is the open [solid torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20solid%20torus,%2C%20embedded%20in%203%2Dspace.), i.e. the solid torus with the boundary torus removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a representation to propose. Is it interesting for your purpose, I don't know...

Consider the set of 3D oriented straight lines that are parallel to vertical plane xOz and intersect base plane xOy.

They can be parameterized by $(x,y,\theta)$, with $(x,y)$ their point of intersection with xOy and angle $\theta$ with respect to horizontal plane.

Edit: One can give of this manifold slightly different representations by replacing the oriented lines

- by their unit vector, or,
- (probably better) by line segments connecting a point $(x_1,y,0)$ to a point $(x_2,y,1)$, with the same $y$, the angle being obtained as $\theta=\operatorname{atan}(1/(x_2-x_1)$. This representation has the advantage to make the connection with affine representation mentionned here and there. A drawback, angles $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$ aren't represented; they have to be "added manually" (!)

Comment: Hi Jean, are you suggesting something like a cube?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the connection. A set of (oriented) lines like this one is a manifold "per se" (one can build a compatible atlas). See the small Edit I am going to add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can build $\Bbb{R}^2 \times S^1$ by first building $\Bbb{R}^2 \times [0, 1]$ and then identifying the top and bottom faces via $(x, y, 0) \sim (x, y, 1)$. (In this space, if you float up to through the top face, you exit out of the bottom face directly vertically below where you started.)